# Adding things to UI on button click

Tags: java, android, firebase, user-interface, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have created a game lobby (it doesn't work) for my app and am trying to figure out how to add an interface to the lobby screen whenever a user creates an open game.

So, currently, I have it so that when a user clicks the create a game button, it adds a game to the Realtime Database in Firebase. This is my createGame method that is called whenever the button is clicked.

```
    public void createLobbyGame () {
    gameMaker = new GameMaker(hp.uid, "hello", wager);

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FCGames").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
            .setValue(gameMaker).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(FlipCoinLobby.this, "Game created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(FlipCoinLobby.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And that works great, it adds a new data tree to my Firebase Database whenever the button is clicked.

So now I am trying to make it so that when the game is created, the screen updates and adds a button and some text like seen below:

[Screen WITH the updated interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSD4a.png)

I am stuck on this one and am hoping somebody can guide me in the right direction.

To summarize my question is: once a user creates an open game, how can I update the screen to display something like I showed in the image with the users name and avatar and a 'Join' button. All of the info I need is stored in the database once a user creates a game, I just don't know how to update the UI in a dynamic state.

Comment: You can use RecyclerView

Comment: Thank you Sinan I will do some research on RecyclerView :)

Comment: You also have an option to launch a new activity with loading the details from firebase database.